Starting a campfire with a log but without any kindling
Recently someone saw our BBQ which is huge and bought wood logs. They were pro campers so was able to have a bonfire. I was not there at that time, but one log was left. I tried starting the fire with cardboard and paper but as you can see from the picture, I was unsuccessful.
What are ways to start a bonfire to sit around or have a camp fire to cook food on when I do not have kindling? Should I try some oil?
How does pro campers do it and is this wood size is too big?


Butane torch works pretty quickly…

@JonCuster Tried that for good 30 minute, when I turned torch off, it stopped burning.

Remember the Fire Triangle - in order to burn, a fire needs

Fuel
Oxygen
Heat

A large piece of wood like that takes a long time to get hot enough to burn, even though it's made of fuel and well-ventilated.
What you need to do is convert a portion of it into kindling which you can burn from smallest to largest (perhaps starting with some thin shavings to act as tinder).  The kindling should burn for long enough to get the log sufficiently hot for it to burn.   This is the same principle you use at home when lighting a coal fire - you always use kindling to get the fuel hot enough to burn itself, rather than trying to light the coal directly from a match.
It works best if you have two or more logs together on your fire (or a deep bed of hot ashes), rather than a single log, so I recommend splitting the rump log after you have created your kindling.  This allows you to get the airflow in the right places.

So I got a bag of logs today so I can learn how to make fire. When you say 'convert porition of it into kindling', how do one do that without a axe? and how much kindling is enough because thinner it will be the faster it will burn?

If you don't have a hand-axe, then you might be able to use a knife to split it.  Also consider using stones as wedges and hammers, if the local geology is suitable.  As to how much, I can't really describe that in a short answer here; I think that's just a matter of experience, so practice whenever you can - perhaps by saving a charred block from your fireplace at home and then finding the minimum kindling you need to re-light it the next day when it's cooled.

I have learned that to burn a big log you start with thinner, smaller pieces of wood as well as fire starter material.
If the log is the only wood you have you start by cutting into it, on one corner, so that flakes of wood can be bend away from the log while still being attached.
It looks a bit like you tried to make a Christmas tree, a series of cuts diagonal on the fibre of the wood each a bit higher than the last.
I doubt you can still do so with the partly burned wood but you might still be able to split it into smaller pieces. If you make kindling out of about 10 % of the log, about half the log at least in fairly even fire wood sized pieces you might get the rest to fully burn.
On the other hand, I have rekindled fires on partly burned wood, so you might just try and see if it works, but you need very flameable stuff, like paper or bbq starter to get it going.

I don't do campfires all that often but do have a wood fire at home.  Wood burns best on top of some already alight fuel - charcoal etc, until it is sufficiently carbonized to act as charcoal itself, at which point it may just go out or will burn almost completely, depending on the type of wood. Chopping into chunks and lighting some, then putting the big lump on top is the way to go.

If you have a sturdy one-bladed knife, position its blade horizontally at a corner, into the grain.  Hold the handle, then using your dominant hand, tap its blade gently on top with a stick, driving it downward along the grain.
Start out trying only a narrow split.  That should split a chunk off.  Don't do this with a folding knife or one that isn't sturdy.  Best wear glasses too for extra safety.
But really, you should be hitting quite softly, with not much more force than hammering a finishing nail into something fragile.
Then, using same technique, spit that chunk into more kindling and repeat.
Now, this will work given a good knife and some dry wood, like a plank.  On a thick solid log, it could work.  But if it doesn't, don't insist, it's only safe if you don't have to use much force. A good sign it isn't going to work is when your knife repeatedly gets wedged and caught in the wood and you have trouble prying it back out.  Another no-no is the piece of wood not being straight, but bent instead - the knife would be hard to control in that case.
In your case, your log looks both thick and fire-hardened so it may very well not work.
  | down
  V
     /
    /
 ------
 |/   |
 |    |
/|    |


